# How can I construct a likelihood function?

Tags: python, data-mining

I have a bunch of data about vampires and non-vampires.  I have a matrix with 2000 subjects, which houses statistics about the subject.

```
#[height(cm), weight(kg), stake aversion, garlic aversion, reflectance, shiny, IS_VAMPIRE?]
```

if `IS_VAMPIRE` is 1, then the subject is a vampire, and 0 otherwise.  I have a couple ideas about how I can construct a function to tell me if a new subject is a vampire or not, but I was wondering if anyone had any really good ideas I could pursue.

Comment: you have a boolean value that tells you yes/no, why do you need anything else?

Comment: You're likely interested in using `scikit-learn` or `pandas` to construct a logistic regression. See [this blog post](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html) for example.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What are your goals?

Comment: Right, so this is a sample from a group of people for which the vampire condition is known.  Suppose I have a new person.  How can I construct a function to give me a probability that the new person is a vampire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the classifier algorithms in `scikit-learn`. If your bunch of data is already labeled, with you knowing who is and isn't a vampire, and you just want to classify the new ones, the easiest approach for a someone new to machine learning and `scikit-learn` is using the decision tree algorithm to build a classifier from your sample data and apply it to new ones.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

```
>>> from sklearn import tree
>>> clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
>>> clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Where X is a list (or a Numpy array) with all your data fields, except for the boolean is_vampire:

```
>>> X = [[v0_height, v0_weight, v0_stake_aversion, v0_garlic_aversion, 
          v0_reflectance, v0_shiny],
         [v1_height, v1_weight, v1_stake_aversion, v1_garlic_aversion, 
          v1_reflectance, v1_shiny],
         ...
        ]
```

And Y is a list with the same length, matching the label for each one:

```
>>> Y = [v0_is_vampire, v1_is_vampire, ...]
```

After being fitted, the tree can be used to check if a new one is a vampire by the following call, where `new` is a sublist like those in X:

```
>>> clf.predict(new)
array([1])
```

Depending on how the range of values is distributed along your data, you may or may not need to feed all values you have to get a decent classification. You'll have to experiment a litttle with that.

Keep in mind that if your Y array provides only 1 and 0 values for the is_vampire label, then this approach will give you the same binary response. If your Y array has float values and you want to quantify the probability of a new one being a vampire with a value between 0 and 1, then just use the `tree.DecisionTreeRegressor` class instead of `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`.

By the way, this probably isn't the best algorithm to do what you're asking, but it's quite straightforward and should get you started. If you get wrong results or performance problems, just get more information on what's a better approach for your case. This link can be very helpful: http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html

Comment: I'm trying to implement your answer, however I am running into some trouble.

Comment: Given your list of vampires, where is_vampire is the last field, X should be [v[:-1] for v in data] and Y [v[-1] for v in data]. Got it? If it doesn't work, start a chat and show me the code, data and error.

Comment: OK, I have everything working.  Is there anyway my output could be a number between 0 and 1?  That way I could interpret it as a probability instead of a binary?

Comment: Read my answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but maybe you could try using variables. so, for example, say hight is high(10), weight is low(1), stake aversion is high(10), garlic aversion is high(10), reflectance is high(10) and shininess is high(10). you then add up all those variables, then put the sum into another variable. If the end variable is, for example, 50 or higher, you are certain it is a vampire, making IS_VAMPIRE true/1. you would need some more states to account for the likeliness and it is a big block of code to write i would think, but if it works(i don't know if it will) then it would be nice. then again i am the most noobiest of the noobs when it comes to programming, maybe i am of no help here :/